# RPG calls through Glassfish connection pooling

Tags: java, glassfish, connection, pool, rpg

Normally we do RPG calls using jt400.jar as follows.

```
AS400 conn = new AS400("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "USERID", "Password");
ProgramCall program = new ProgramCall(conn, "/XXX.LIB/YYYY.LIB/ZZZZZ.PGM",
parameters);
program.run();
```

I'm working on a project that i need to execute the above RPG program using a connection pool established on a GlassFish server. The connection pool is created using below settings

> ```
> <jdbc-resource pool-name="arix" jndi-name="jdbc/ArixSystemResource"></jdbc-resource>
> <jdbc-connection-pool max-pool-size="8" datasource-classname="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" steady-pool-size="4"  name="ARIXPool" >
>   <property name="password" value="XXXX"></property>
>   <property name="user" value="XXXXX"></property>
>   <property name="servername" value="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"></property>
> </jdbc-connection-pool>
> <jdbc-resource pool-name="arix" jndi-name="jdbc/ArixSystemResource"></jdbc-resource>
> ```

I can get a JDBC connection by using the below code

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource das = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/ArixSystemResource");
Connection conn = das.getConnection();
```

But, is there any way to get a AS400 object from the above data source in order to call RPGs. Or can i re-configure the connection pool to retrieve AS400 objects. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `new AS400()` create a JDBC connection? My guess would be 'no' since JDBC does not require an AS400 object. Maybe you need to create an AS400 connection pool, not sure how to do that. Maybe you need a custom class.

Comment: Yes i already have a custom class for that. I;m trying to create a connection pool in the servlet container